# Behaviour of webapplication seems to depend on my datasource?

Tags: java, database, jsf

I'm running a JSF-Webapplication on a GlassFish v3.1.2

If I test it locally everything works fine. Now **I only change the datasource** and I get some strange bevavior:

For example I have a command button which invokes some action to receive data from a database and I want to display this data in a datatable on the same page.
**With my local database this works fine, but if I use the other database** (which is running on a different server in the local intranet), **the action is fired** (I have checked this with some System.out's) **but the ajax-update of my datatable does not work.** If I reload the page after clicking my ajax-button the correct data is displayed, also if I use a non-ajax-button.

I do not even know what I should look for .. any ideas?

---

Im using

- Primfaces 3.4.2
- JSF 2 (Mojarra)
- local Database is Oracle 10g XE
- server Database is Oracle 11g
- jdbc-driver is the latest ojdbc6.jar from oracle-website

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance, Fant

---

> ```
> Http-response-header:
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7), JSF/2.0
> Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 5610
> Date: Sat, 08 Dec 2012 02:05:08 GMT
> ```

---

I also tried to write a PhaseListener to give me some feedback, but this was not very helpful either. Every phase is finished succesful and after my action is performed, an response is send to the client (and the client receives the response as I can see in the Firefox-Addon)
Even the Getter-method of the List that I want to display in my dataTable is called before the htpp-response is send, so I think there is everything fine with the response itself. But the dataTable that I want to rerender is still showing the old data.

Comment: Please elaborate "does not work" in developer's perspective instead of enduser's perspective. The ajax-update is a relatively complex process involving a lot of individual steps (basically .. rendering the XML output, sending the HTTP response, retrieving it in client, parsing the XML, updating the HTML DOM tree). Which steps succeeded and which not? And how exactly not? It may be helpful to post relevant parts of the HTTP response of the ajax request of both the successful and failed cases here.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your comment. i dont know that much about all this. How may I see the http-response? all I managed is to fetch the http-header of the response (with a mozilla addon) (I've added it to the question)

Comment: In Chrome/IE9/Firebug, just press F12 and open the *Network* tab.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Do you have any code like: try { } catch (Exception e) { /* nothing here */}.  If you do, you may be receiving exceptions on the server which are being ignored. In general, **never** do this; at the very least **log** the exception, but better let it fail so you get early warning of such problems.

Comment: OK, you're using Firefox. Install Firebug. Press F12. Open the "Net" tab. Fire the ajax request. Click the ajax request entry in the "Net" tab. Click the "Response" tab. You'd be interested in exactly this information of both the successful and failed cases. The generated HTML has to be exactly the same. If it is, then the problem is in client side. If it is not, then the problem is in server side. Once we know which side is causing the problem, then we can continue with further nailing down the root cause.

Comment: I'm sorry that i didnt found the time earlier to write a response. The generated HTML is correct in both cases, but taking a look in it gave me a hint, so I actually found out, what is causing the error. I have got a character-field in my database, which sometimes containts a null-character. I still don't know *why* this is causing a problem (only during the ajax-rerender), but know i can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but the ajax-update of my datatable does not work*

This is most likely caused by a XML syntax error. The ajax update involves the steps of retrieving the XML response from the server, parsing it and finding the to-be-updated elements in the HTML DOM tree and replacing their content with new HTML which is enclosed in the XML response. Using webbrowser's builtin (Chrome/IE9) or 3rd party (Firebug) webdeveloper toolset you can track the HTTP traffic and inspect the HTTP response in its entirety and you can also debug JavaScript code with breakpoints. This should give you clues as to the cause of the problem.

Provided that the generated HTML code in the XML response is exactly the same (which is a fair assumption, provided that webapp's code is not been changed when you change the datasource), then that can only be caused by a difference in the data which is obtained from the DB. Apparently the change in the datasource also involved a change in the physical database server which in turn thus provides somewhat different data.

Based on the comments on the question, the root cause turns out to be a [`NUL` character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) coming straight from the other DB which ended up in the XML response, causing the webbrowser's XML parser to choke because it's an illegal character in XML. [The XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Char) specifies only the following characters as valid:

> #### 2.2 Characters
>
> ...
>
> *Character Range*
>
> ```
> Char   ::=   #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD]  /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate 
>              | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]                               blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
> ```

The `#x0` (the `NUL` character) is not among them.

You should have noticed a XML parsing error in the console of the webbrowser's webdeveloper toolset.

Comment: In my last comment I didn't mean the generated HTML but the HTTP response. I will have a look for such a XML parsing error, just to see and learn :) ... Thank you very much once again, your replies have been very helpful. Fant

Comment: The generated HTML **in** the XML response (in the HTTP response) :)